# watching cloned input in nuxtjs vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

I'm facing a problem with watching cloned inputs
How can it possible to watch any changes inside each input for each client

is it possible to use 'Deep' here?

**ClientsForm.vue**

```html
<template>
 <div v-for="(client, index) as clients" :key="index">
  ~ 
  <input v-model="client.address.code">
 </div>
</template>
<script>
 export default{
 ~
 data (){
  return{
   ~
   clients: json.parse(json.stringify(this.$store.getters['STATE']))
  }
 },
 methods: {
  clone(){
   this.clients.push({
    ~
    address: {
     code: ""
    }
   })
  }
 }
 watch: {
  'client.address.code': function(oldVal, newVal){
    //things todo
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: ..or just put an @input on the input and fire off a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution in terms of future debugging and overall simplicity is to create a component for the input in order to observe the changes in each of them separately.

So your current component would look something like this:

```js
<template>
 <div v-for="(client, index) as clients" :key="index">
  <AddressCode :code="client.address.code" />
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import AddressCode from '@/components/AddressCode.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    AddressCode
  },
  data (){
  return{
   ~
   clients: json.parse(json.stringify(this.$store.getters['STATE']))
  }
 },
 methods: {
  clone(){
   this.clients.push({
    ~
    address: {
     code: ""
    }
   })
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

And the `AddressCode.vue` file (the file of your new component) would look something like this:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="code">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['code'],
  watch: {
    code (oldVal, newVal) {
      // todos
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Have in mind that this should work if the `AddressCode.vue` file is located in the `components` folder. You should change the `import` statement in the first file if you want to have your `AddressCode` component living in a different folder.

Comment: yeah I liked your idea.. so easy to implement... thanks ^^